# How to set or override target= "_blank" in anchor tag in 'sanitize-html' ?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) in my project. Say suppose I get a mail which has anchor tag, something like this: 

`this is to test something <a href="https://www.google.com/">open google</a>`

This mail appears in my mail box like this : 

`this is to test something open google`

Which opens google.com in the same tab. But **I need to open in new tab**. 
Here is my code.

```
__html = sanitizeHTML(children, {
        allowedTags: sanitizeHTML.defaults.allowedTags.concat([ 'img' ]),
        allowedAttributes: {
          '*': [ 'href', 'align', 'alt', 'center', 'bgcolor', 'style', 'width' ],
          'img': ['src'],
          'a' : ['target'] 
        },
       }
```

Here I want to set or override target = "_blank" . How to achieve that in [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html) ?

Unfortunately I could not find a tag for sanitize-html.

Comment: Have you tried adding `'a'` into `'*': ['a', 'href', 'align', 'alt', 'center', 'bgcolor', 'style', 'width']` and tried using `transformTags`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to READ.MD/doc and your problem description, something like:

```
__html = sanitizeHTML(children, {
    ...,
    transformTags: {
      'a': function(tagName, attribs) {// simpleTransform also possible...
       return {
        tagName: 'a',//tagName
        attribs: {
            target: '_blank',
            href:   '*'
        }
    };
}
```

...should do it.

> EDIT:

A better solution preserving the current (allowed!) attributes:

```
....
 transformTags: {
   'a': sanitizeHtml.simpleTransform('a', {target: '_blank'})
 }
```

Comment: But not able to hover the link

Comment: I seriously don't know why it is not working still opening in the same tab.

Comment: Yes it works. The only thing is we need to keep ```'a' : ['target'] ```  in ```allowedAttributes```

Comment: Thank you @xerx593